# Why does SQL Server think that CHAR(49) AND CHAR(185) are the same?

Tags: sql-server, ascii

Why does SQL Server think that CHAR(49) AND CHAR(185) are the same?

When a 1 is entered into a column either of type NVARCHAR or TEXT, it sees it as both CHAR (49) (One) and CHAR (185) (Superscript One)

Example data:

```
SELECT CAST('1111' AS TEXT)  AS col1 INTO CharTest;
```

Select scripts:

```
SELECT * FROM CharTest WHERE col1 LIKE '%'+CHAR(49)+'%';
SELECT * FROM CharTest WHERE col1 LIKE '%'+CHAR(185)+'%';
```

Both statements return: 1111

Comment: I tested the scripts . and it works perfectly, the only one script retrieves  1111, and the other doesn't.

Comment: is it the collation that you have in force?

Comment: Your Example Data is not matched with the Description of issue ! , SELECT 1111 it means the dataType is `int`, so update your question via correct example `NVARCHAR` or `TEXT`

Comment: @Ahmed - Good spot - you can change the sample to insert '1111' and get the same effects though, varying the COLLATION seems to vary what is returned by LIKE '%1%'

Comment: @Cato I actually changed the sample to be '1111', but still the issue not created , because it is created only with `NVARCHAR` or `TEXT` and the data type of  '1111' is `VARCHAR`

Comment: My bad edited script

Comment: Not the same scenario, and a different RDBMS, but essentially the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102371/sql-doesnt-differentiate-u-and-%C3%BC-although-collation-is-utf8mb4-unicode-ci/41104208#41104208

Comment: LIKE is by default case-insensitive. And `'1' = char(185) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS` evaluates as true, while a case-sensitive collation  `'1' = char(185) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` evaluates as false. So the exponent number  of 1 counts as a different case. Who knew?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a different collation should do this

```
SELECT * FROM CharTest WHERE 
        col1 LIKE '%'+CHAR(49)+'%' COLLATE  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
SELECT * FROM CharTest WHERE 
        col1 LIKE '%'+CHAR(185)+'%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
```

Comment: Voting up , nice catch.